# How to read pdf content from server and save in file?

Tags: android

I have a server link from where I need to read the pdf content. I used the following code but it give result in some other format.

```
public String readPDF() throws Exception
{
     BufferedReader in = null;
     String page = "";
     try {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
         request.setURI(new URI("http://14.140.41.194/monali/i.pdf"));
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         in = new BufferedReader
         (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
         String line = "";
         String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line + NL);
         }
         in.close();
         page = sb.toString();
         } finally {
         if (in != null) {
             try {
                 in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
         }
     }         
     return page;       
}
```

---

```
05-31 19:00:49.894: INFO/System.out(624): page .. %PDF-1.4
05-31 19:00:49.894: INFO/System.out(624): %����
05-31 19:00:49.903: INFO/System.out(624): 15 0 obj
05-31 19:00:49.903: INFO/System.out(624): <</Length 2496
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): /Subtype /XML
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): /Type /Metadata
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): >>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): stream
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): <?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): <x:xmpmeta x:xmptk="3.1-701" xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <xmp:CreateDate>2011-05-20T05:46:02Z</xmp:CreateDate>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <xmp:CreatorTool>Nitro PDF Professional  (6, 0, 1, 8)</xmp:CreatorTool>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <xmp:ModifyDate>2011-05-20T05:46:04Z</xmp:ModifyDate>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <xmp:MetadataDate>2011-05-20T05:46:04Z</xmp:MetadataDate>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     </rdf:Description>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <dc:creator>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):         <rdf:Seq>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):           <rdf:li></rdf:li>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):         </rdf:Seq>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       </dc:creator>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <dc:title>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):         <rdf:Alt>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):           <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default"></rdf:li>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):         </rdf:Alt>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       </dc:title>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <dc:description>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):         <rdf:Alt>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):           <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default"/>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):         </rdf:Alt>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       </dc:description>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     </rdf:Description>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <pdf:Keywords></pdf:Keywords>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <pdf:Producer>Nitro PDF Professional  (6, 0, 1, 8)</pdf:Producer>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     </rdf:Description>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):       <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:3e7ef8a9-a526-45bf-9db1-a31533c20f86</xmpMM:DocumentID>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):     </rdf:Description>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):   </rdf:RDF>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624): </x:xmpmeta>
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):                                                                                                     
05-31 19:00:49.916: INFO/System.out(624):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on the following code to store pdf file

```
try {

                        URL u = new URL("http://14.140.41.194/monali/i.pdf");
                        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        c.setDoOutput(true);
                        c.connect();
                        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName,"my.pdf"));


                        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len1 = 0;
                        while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                            f.write(buffer,0, len1);
                    }

                        f.close();
```

Thanks
Sunil